# Converting a string to JSON in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am consuming a webservice in node js and it returns me the response in this strange format. I have to extract certain values by passing the key names and I would like to convert the response to a JSON for ease of parsing. How should I go about it ?

This is what I get from the webservice

```
Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=*******;Password=
*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Conn
ect Timeout=180;Application Name=*****
```

I want to extract DataSource , UserID, Password.

Comment: Split to pairs with `.split(';')`, then split each pair to k/v with `.split('=')`. This might be harder if values can include `;` and `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dario's answer basically does the trick, but it's worth knowing that Node's `querystring` module does this sort of stuff "for free".

The code

```
const qs = require('querystring');
const s = `Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=*******;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=180;Application Name=*****`;
console.log(qs.parse(s, ';', '='));
```

outputs:

```
{ 'Data Source': '*******',
  'Initial Catalog': '****',
  'User ID': '*******',
  Password: '*******',
  MultipleActiveResultSets: 'True',
  'Min Pool Size': '5',
  'Max Pool Size': '5000',
  'Connect Timeout': '180',
  'Application Name': '*****' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily parse it with [String split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
const obj = response.split(';', 2).reduce((json, pair) => {
  const tokens    = pair.split('=', 2);
  json[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
  return json;
}, {});
```

You can manipulate it, deleting or extracting values, and finally encoding it in JSON with `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

**Note**: as Oleg V. Volkov comments, if the source string contains delimeters (';' and '=') in key or value, it will don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the returned pattern is constant, it can be achieved using regexp:

```
var result = str.match(/Source=(.*);Initial.*ID=(.*);Password=(.*);Multiple/)
```

And then take your desired values from matched groups.

```
DataSource = result[1];
UserId = result[2];
Password = result[3];
```